# Evaluating GETDATE twice in a statement - will it always evaluate to be the same?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, getdate

suppose

```
isnull(some_column, getdate()) >= getdate()
```

where logic is if some_column is null this expression should always be true. However will this always be so (since between two evaluations of getdate() some time has passed and they won't be equal) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, is not safe. You are facing so called [runtime constants](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) expressions, of which `GETDATE()` is the bookcase example, which are evaluate once at query startup and the subsequently the cached evaluated value is used. However *each occurence is evaluated separately once* and the two evaluation can fall on the separate sides of the datetime precision boundary, resulting in two *different* values.

A simple test reveals how this happens:

```
declare @cnt int = 0, @i int = 0
while @cnt = 0 
begin
    select @cnt = count(*)
    from master..spt_values 
    where getdate() != getdate();
    set @i += 1;
    if @cnt != 0
        raiserror(N'@cnt = %d this shoudl not happen but it dit after @i = %d', 16, 1, @cnt, @i);
end
```

In my case this was hit right away:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
@cnt = 2515 this shoudl not happen but it dit after @i = 694
```

I'm not addressing the question how to better do this (you already got plenty of advice) but the underlying question whether your assumption about the run-time execution is right (is not):

**`GETDATE()` twice in a statement will be evaluate twice**

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for true in the condition, you don't need to use `getDate()` twice. Just put in a very large date instead...

For example:

```
isnull(some_column, '2999-01-01') >= getDate()
```

as in

```
declare @some_column(datetime)
select case when isnull(@some_column,'2999-01-01') >= getdate() then 1 else 0 end
```

which returns 1.

Alternatively you can do it properly and check for the null explicitly:

```
(some_column >= getdate() or some_column is null)
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2000 and previous versions, getdate() is a deterministic function evaluated ONCE per SQL sentence. From 2005 and on, getdate is NOT deterministic, it's evaluated each time so you should assign the value to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you *are* invoking `GETDATE()` twice, this *may* fail, though most of the time it will work right.

You can do the following to mitigate:

```
DECLARE currentDate DATETIME

SELECT currentDate = GETDATE()

isnull(some_column, currentDate) >= currentDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use date. I mean there is no reason to ask sql server to evaluate/process for a default true condition.
You can instead use

```
isnull(some_column, 2) >= 1
```